# What's the difference between SocketConnection vs DCOM Connection

Tags: delphi, com

Does anybody knows the difference between `TSocketConnection` and `TDCOMConnection`??
In a application that receives heavy serial requests, at the same time, which one is better to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the transport which carries the remote call parameters back and forth between the client and the appserver. TDCOMConnection uses Microsoft's DCOM to dispatch remote calls, TSocketConnection uses a simple binary protocol over a TCP/IP socket connection (see SConnect unit) to a running scktsrvr.exe process. Both TDCOMConnection and TSocketConnection require Automation-compatible COM interfaces.

As to which one is better: probably TSocketConnection but I'm not sure. DCOM used to be considered difficult to configure and manage/secure, I don't know if that's changed in the meantime. Personally I've only used TSocketConnection, TWebConnection and TLocalConnection, I never needed TDCOMConnection.

Comment: In the Socket, each call to the server generates a new thread of the remote datamodule? Or the instance is shared to all callers?

Comment: A separate thread per client connection. The server scktsrvr.dpr comes with source code, see TSocketDispatcherThread in ScktMain.pas.

Comment: Ok thank you! i'll study about those components, i just want a overview  from someone experienced

Comment: Hello, Is It Possible DCOM Use Internal Socket during connection?